# Prevent second fancybox from open when another fancybox instance is already open

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

On my site, i have a two fancybox instance

1. open youtube video when someone clicks on div
2. open newsletter popup after 25 seconds when someone visit site.

The problem is when someone clicks on div and start watching the video and if 25 seconds pass in meantime, it will open newsletter popup and close the already open video popup. This will create bad experience for site users can anyone having solutions?

Below is the code for both fancybox instance

video popup jquery

```
jQuery("#yblock").click(function() {
jQuery.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'aspectRatio'         : true,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'     : 780,
        'height'        : 500,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'                   : {
             'wmode'        : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        },
        helpers                  : {
            'overlay': {
            'locked': false
                       }
        }
```

Newsletter popup jquery

```
jQuery(function ($) {
setTimeout(function () {
                beginNewsletterForm();
            }, 25000);
});

function beginNewsletterForm() {
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'padding': '0px',
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'inline',
        'href': '#newsletter_popup',
        'onComplete': function () {
            $.cookie('newsletter_popup', 'shown');
        },
        'tpl': {
            closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close fancybox-newsletter-close" href="javascript:;"></a>'
        },
        'helpers': {
            overlay: {
                locked: true
            }
        }
    });
    jQuery('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');
}
```

I want to prevent second fancybox to open if first fancybox is already open

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my english before. For open 2 modal at once using the same plugin (fancybox) may cause conflict in action. you can try open the video box with fancybox and open the newsletter box with [bootstrap modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) or another plugin. may this help. thanks